# CSS cursor zoom-in/out

Tags: css, google-chrome, mouse-cursor

I have buttons to zoom-in or zoom-out content. In firefox cursor works well (its like magnifier with `+`). But in chrome I have default cursor. This is my code:

```
.button.zoom-in {
   ...
   cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

Can someone help me, why that works in forefox and in chrome not? Also, other cursors like help, move, pointer... works in chrome too.

Comment: First Google result: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/ tl;dr: use -webkit- prefixes.

Comment: You could write it as answer. Thanks, I didnt mind it could be CSS3

Comment: I don't think it's a good answer as it is essentially just a link to an outside source. Repeating it here is an answer is redundant really.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: Put the answer here on StackOverflow. Just because the answer exists somewhere on the Internet, doesn't mean it shouldn't be here as well, otherwise StackOverflow would be fairly empty and every response would be "go somewhere else for the answer".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Chrome you have to use the prefixed-property-value:

```
.button.zoom-in {
   ...
   cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
   cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H24Jh/1/)**.

Comment: I also noted that if you put two styles inline with the same attr chrome takes the last defined value for that attr. dont inline style lol

Answer (score 5):

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) from Mozilla is an excellent reference to different cursors as well as browser compatibility for each.

For the zoom-in and zoom-out cursors, the following should work for Chrome 1.0+, Firefox 1.0+, Opera 11.6+ and Safari 3.0+.  Zoom-in/out is not supported by IE.

```
.button.zoom-in {
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in; 
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
```